# Accessing this.state in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

Hi I'm new to React so bear with me. I'm want to store geoposition as a state. Seems nifty since any change in position will trigger a render, which is exactly what I want. During development I have a button that manual triggers the event by accessing the `lastPosition`. But when I do. The state is "undefined". Any clue why?

```
export default class FetchProject extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            initialPosition: 'unknown',
            lastPosition: 'unknown',
        };
    }

    //code that sets lastposition
    componentDidMount() {
        ....
    }

    _onPressGET (){
        console.log("PressGET -> " + this.state); //undefined
        var northing=this.state.initialPosition.coords.latitude; 
        //triggers error
    }

    render() {
       return (    
           <View style={styles.container}>
               <TouchableHighlight onPress = {this._onPressGET} style = {styles.button}>
                  <Text>Fetch mailbox</Text>
               </TouchableHighlight>
           </View>
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the piece of code where you are using `_onPressGet` ? (Probably your `render` function).

Comment: Yup. In `render()`. Added the missing code above.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When using ES6 classes in RN, watch for binding `this` - `this` may not be what you think unless you bind it.

```
onPress = { this._onPressGet.bind(this) }
```

or in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    initialPosition: 'unknown',
    lastPosition: 'unknown'
  };

  this._onPressGet = this._onPressGet.bind(this);
}
```

or maybe the most elegant way

```
_onPressGet = () => {
  // Function body
}
```

In order from least to most preferential.

Comment: Thanks. It works. (But `this.state.initialPosition.coords.latitude`still triggers an error, but that's another story) Why does it get `this`confused? Looking at the code, it seems pretty obvious to me that `this`should refer to the object the method was declared in.

Comment: In this case `this` probably refers to the object that the function is being fired from, like a button or a textbox.

Comment: Great answer. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to **bind** `this.handleClick` and pass it to `onClick`, this will be `undefined` when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without `()` after it, such as `onClick={this.handleClick}`, you should bind that method.