# "c.call is not a function" error with firebase in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am trying to use firebase in my react-native project for user-logging in/out processes. When I click the button, firebase.auth().SignInWithEmailAndPassword function is executed but it gives error that it says "c.call is not a function", which is occured in auth.js.

I couldn't find any related answer about the error.

[screenshot of the error] (https://ibb.co/TPQCFZr)

```
onButtonClick() {
        const { email, password } = this.state;

        this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
        .catch(
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(this.onCreateSuccess.bind(this))
            .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this))
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know react native but the problem probably comes from the fact that you are not passing a callback function to the `then()` method.

Try the following:

```
onButtonClick() {
        const { email, password } = this.state;

        this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(userCredential => this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
        .catch(err => {
            //err
        });
    }
```

---

See the documentation for the `then()` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), which explains that:

> The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments:
>   callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

and that the callback function for the failure case is optional.

---

You are actually doing the same with the `catch()` method. See doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch).

---

Finally, note that you should not treat all the errors from the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method in the same way. There are different cases for such an error: wrong password, user not found, etc. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithemailandpassword

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it didn't solve the problem.. I wrote the inside of then() method like (() => {this.....}) but onLoginSuccess method wasn't binded to then method, onLoginSuccess wasn't executed.

Comment: Are you sure that `this` is what you expect? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340958/accessing-this-state-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

You should use async/await and 
also handle all throwables using try...catch construction.
Example code :

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

async function register(email, password) {
  try {
    await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
}
```